# Swift constraint warning

Tags: swift, constraints, warnings

I tried everything but can't find the solution for this warning XCode throws at me:

---

I have a tableView with cells.

The cells are dynamic height, because they have a view inside them: "message bubble".

Inside the message bubble, I have a label. If you click on a message bubble, the label's top-bottom margin constraint are expanding.

And there is a time label over the message bubble.

I get this warning:

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-08-15 10:50:40.805762+0200 PipeTest[2521:879876] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0296670 V:[UILabel:0x102790380'Hehe']-(14)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10278ff60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c02945f0 V:|-(14)-[UILabel:0x102790380'Hehe']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10278ff60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0299780 UIView:0x102790b20.height == 27   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0296d00 UILabel:0x102773e60' 9 minutes ago'.height == 18   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c02926b0 UIView:0x102790b20.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x102784510.bottomMargin   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c02963a0 V:[UIView:0x10278ff60]-(7.67)-[UIView:0x102790b20]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0298a10 V:[UILabel:0x102773e60' 9 minutes ago']-(3)-[UIView:0x10278ff60]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0297070 UILabel:0x102773e60' 9 minutes ago'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x102784510.topMargin   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0296760 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x102784510.height == 94   (active)>"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to share you code which shows the constraints.

Comment: I can't say which constraint is causing the problems without looking at the actual code, but try this: 
Lower the constraint priority on some of the fixed size constraints (like height or width). Constraint's priority default value is 1000, so lowering it to 999 should do it. (try this approach with different constraints one by one until you find the one that is causing you troubles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined several height constraints (dimensions) as well as vertical constraints. Probably, you have over constrained.
As proposed, lower the priorities of tome vertical constraints.